# How to interpret iOS crash log from Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I got a crash log from Crashlytics, see below. I don't know what `+ 56` means in `line 3`. I am not sure if it is related to line number in the source code.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1826f0910 objc_msgSend + 16
1  CoreFoundation                 0x183406360 -[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:] + 56
2  BLESupport                     0x10084a63c -[CustomPeripheral getDeviceParamsDidFinish:dictionary:paramType:error:] + 380
3  BLESupport                     0x100850ab4 -[CustomPeripheral peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:] + 4032
```

Answer (score 3):

The "+ 56" is an offset in the compiled binary, not a line number in the source code.

```
1  CoreFoundation                 0x183406360 -[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:] + 56
```

Xcode provides you to **backtrace log** and provides information about active frames to help you trace the issue.

The above crash log can be understand as follows.

**1 -** that is the frame at which it was crashed. 0 is the top most

**CoreFoundation -** it is the responsible framework behind the crash.

**0x183406360 -** the address on the disk at which timeIntervalSinceDate function exists.

**[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:] + 56 -** This is the important part, where it says about the function and + 56 is an offset from function address that crashed.

Thanks matt for pointing it out.

EDIT:
Basically, there are three types of crash reports

1. unsymbolicated - This contains only addresses and offset
2. Partially Symbolicated - This shows Base Address Of Method + Method Name + Offset From the base address
3. Fully Symbolicated. - This shows base address + Method Name + FileName:LineNumber

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the `+ 56` is an offset from function address. It is not a line number.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for pointing it out, I have edited my answer based on your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The convention used is:

```
<address> <name of symbol> <offset into symbol> <line number>
```

So, for your line 3, above, the `+ 56` indicates that the PC was 56 bytes into the function `-[NSDate timeIntervalSinceDate:]`. It is not the line number.

In order for Crashlytics, or any other service to provide line number information, they need access to debug symbol information. A very common source of this information is a dSYM. So, in order to provide line number information for this NSDate function, you'd need the dSYM for CoreFoundation. Only Apple has this. Of course, since you don't have the code for this function anyways, having the line number probably wouldn't help very much.